# CNN model does not load inside Visual Studio 2017 using dnn.readNetFromTensorflow

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, dotnetnuke

I have created a simple CNN model which I froze into `tf_model.pb` file and I have tried loading it using open cv `dnn.readNetFromTesnorflow(model_path)` method inside Jupyter Notebook and it works perfectly. The problem is when I try to load it inside Visual Studio 2017, for some reason it does not load correctly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    class CharNet {

        private:
            Net network;
            string output_layer;

        public:

            CharNet(string path) {
                try {
                    cout << "Path: "<< path << endl;

                    network = readNetFromTensorflow(path);

                    vector<String> network_layers = network.getLayerNames();
                    cout << "There are "<<network_layers.size()<< " layers" << endl;
                    for (int i = 0; i < network_layers.size(); i++) {
                        cout << network_layers[i] << endl;
                        if ( network_layers[i].find("Softmax") != std::string::npos ) {
                            cout << "Output Layer: "<< network_layers[i] << endl;
                            output_layer = network_layers[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (cv::Exception& e) {
                    cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
                    if (network.empty()) {
                        cerr << "Can't load the model" << endl;
                    }
                }
            }

    };

    string model = "C:/Users/stefan_cepa995/source/repos/OpenCV_Test/OpenCV_Test/tf_model.pb";

    CharNet* obj = new CharNet(model);

    return 0;

}
```

Since the model is not loaded correctly I never enter the for loop. Does anyone have any idea whats going on?

Comment: is the path relative or absolute? Typically, starting your application from Visual Studio directly, the working directory is different from what you might expect. Try it with absolute path (e.g. "C:/myModels/model.extension"). If that works, have a look at the "working directory" setting of your project somewhere in the general properties -> debugging, afair.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Sadly the path is absolute and the code still does not work. I just cant think of anything what might be the problem

Comment: any other dependency missing? If it works out of visual studio but not in the visual studio environment, please try to change the working directory in the project settings anyways. I don't know Jupyter Notebook, is there anything special about that environment?

Comment: what's the console output from your application? Is there an exception caught (output: "Exception: ...") or is there the output "There are 0 layers"?

Comment: I really wish I could tell you more, I configured VS 2017 so I can use openCV and its modules in it, I am getting no ERRORS when I run my code, I just get a vector with 1 element, and that element is NULL value.